# Get return value from stored procedure on linked server in SQL Server

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, oracle12c, stored-functions

I have a stored function on an Oracle DB, that I'm executing from a procedure in SQL Server. The function in Oracle returns a boolean value. The trouble I'm having is getting that value once it's executed.

Here's the call:

```
EXEC  ('DECLARE
            x boolean;
        BEGIN
            x := dba.ws_pack.truncate_table;
        END;'
) AT DBLINK;
```

Which works for executing the function and truncating the table.

So any idea how I get the value of x, or how I can execute this and get the return value directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I got to work:

```
select @return_value = val from openquery(DBLINK, 'select dba.ws_pack.truncate_table val from dual');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
EXEC ('BEGIN ? := dba.ws_pack.truncate_table; END;', @ReturnValue ) AT DBLINK;
```

Comment: Couldn't get the above solution to work, but here's what I did get: select @return_value = val from openquery(DBLINK, 'select dba.ws_pack.truncate_table val from dual');